# Can I get an instance of outer class using reflection on inner class type?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to use scala reflection to achieve this:

```
val labelBar = Named("bar")
val labelFoo = NamedFunc("foo", (i: Int) => println(i))

val i = newInstance[
    labelBar.Var[Int] +
    labelFoo.Func[Int => Unit]
  ]

i.foo(2)
i.bar = 20
```

It uses a newInstace method to create a new object with specified members. To allow dynamic members, I use the scala's Dynamic class.
newInstance takes an implicit TypeTag argument. Var is an inner classes for the Named class:

```
case class Named(name: String) {
  outer =>
  class Var[T]() {
    def getOuter: Named = outer
  }
}

class +[A, B]
```

My problem is that I can't use reflectClass on Type representing inner class. It throws this:

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: class asVar is an inner class, use reflectClass on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ClassMirror
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.scala$reflect$runtime$JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$abort(JavaMirrors.scala:115)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.ErrorInnerClass(JavaMirrors.scala:117)
at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.reflectClass(JavaMirrors.scala:183)
```

Is there a way to get around it? Does Scala even hold this instance?

**Edit 1:**
newInstance method doesn't take the labelFoo instance as an argument, so I can't follow the advice in exception message.

Comment: Note that you need to obtain `labelFoo` and `labelBar` from your arguments _somehow_, or you can't access the name and the function you need. Once you do, you can follow the advice. If you are trying to "cheat" by somehow instantiating `labelBar.Var` without having access to `labelBar` and then calling `getOuter` on it, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. If I understand it correctly, outer class instance is a 'component' of nested class type. I can't do something like this:
    `val label: labelBar.Var = new labelFoo.Var()`
It would make it possible to use scala type parameters to pass values.

Comment: The value itself isn't. You can't do the above even if `labelBar` and `labelFoo` have the same value. The symbol (or, more generally, a stable path) is, and can be accessed through `TypeRef` as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. I will try to do it with macros, maybe it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get around it?

Yes, and the error message clearly says what it is:

> use reflectClass on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ClassMirror

I.e. instead of `mirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)` call `mirror.reflect(labelBar).reflectClass(classSymbol)` (assuming you want to get a `ClassMirror` for a class nested in `labelBar`). To find the instance, you can try to match `typeTag.tpe` against [`TypeRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/scala-reflect/?_ga=1.187367656.1907900041.1427697475#scala.reflect.api.Types$TypeRef).

Comment: The problem is that the newInstance method doesn't take a labelBar as an argument, so I can't do what the exception says. The only thing I can access there is a TypeTag of the nested class.

Comment: "To find the instance, you can try to match typeTag.tpe against TypeRef."